# How do I get my local git stuff into BlueMix?

Tags: git, import, clojure, ibm-cloud

I created a zip formatted file from a Leiningen generated Clojure project. I based my workflow on "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-suggest-app/index.html?ca=drs-#N10109" by Oliver Siebenmarck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question title I understood that you have a some code in GIT & you want to push it on

Bluemix.

you need to cd to the local GIT code & start by cloning the local repository using the GIT URL from

either the Blue mix application dashboard or the BUILD & DEPLOY page:

$ git clone https://hub.jazz.net/git/jazzhubdemouser/mycoolwebappdemo

Then, change to your GIT clone directory and do a GIT add, commit and push as shown:

$ cd ..

$ git add *

$ git commit -m "Changing title of app"

[master bf26680] Changing title of app

1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

$ git push

After this step your code will be moved to bluemix.

Below is the reference tutorial for this:

https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditor/

Answer (score 0):

1. install git on your local machine.

2.check the various option available got git bash.

http://git-scm.com/doc

3.Login to bluemix and use add git button in devops.

4.clone your git code on bluemix,all the sample steps are already provided, use [devops tutorial](https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditor/)

5. Once final push is success,you have your app running on bluemix.